# Preencher uma ListBox com dados vindos de checkBoxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou com problemas a preencher a minha Listbox, consigo preencher a Listbox com os valores da checkboxes das não com as Labels correspondentes.
Estou com falta de ideias como vou fazer isto.

A lista de checkBoxes é preenchida com jquery, da seguinda maneira:

```
 itensNomesCatequizandos.append(catequizando.Nome + '<br />');
 itensCheckBoxCatequizandos.append('<input type="checkbox" name="SelectedCatequizandos[]" value="' + catequizando.PessoaID + '">' + '<br />');
```

A minha ListBox preenche todos nomes numa só minha:

```
<script>
    function addListbox() {
        var itensListBoxCatequizandos = $("#SelectedCatequizandos");
        itensListBoxCatequizandos.empty();
        var myCheckboxes = new Array();
        $("input:checked").each(function () {
            myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
            $.each($('.NomesCatequizando'), function (index, Nome) {
                $.each(myCheckboxes, function (index, value) {
                    itensListBoxCatequizandos.append('<option value="' + value.myCheckboxes + '">' + $(Nome).text() + '</option>');
                });


            });
        });

    }
</script>
```

Onde recebo o texto para preencher a ListBox:

```
  <td id="NomesCatequizando" class="NomesCatequizando"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma POC bem simples, espero que ajude:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" /> Um
<input type="checkbox" value="2" /> Dois
<input type="checkbox" value="3" /> Tres

<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function() {  
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){     
    var $lista = $('#lista');
    var value = $(this).val();
    var $item = $('<li/>').attr('data-id', value).html(value);        
        if(this.checked) {
        $item.appendTo($lista);
    } else {
      $lista.find('li[data-id='+ value +']').remove();
    }
    });
})
```

Teste no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8k25z2f5/).

Comment: Não foi a minha solução mas também funciona.